# CORS Missing Allow Origin on Laravel Echo Server with Socket.io and Redis

Tags: laravel, server, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

Hi I am getting Following error after adding  on my view page of laravel application.

I am using Windows 10 .

**CORS Missing Allow Origin**

[CORS Missing Allow Origin Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRHQD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Steps will resolve "CORS Missing Allow Origin" Error for your Echo Server

STEP-1:
Add "transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] // Fix CORS error!" Code inside your Echo Server Setup File (public\js\laravel-echo-setup.js) like following code:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] // Fix CORS error!
});
```

STEP-2:
Build Your Code Using "npm run dev" command
Restart your Laravel Echo Server Using "laravel-echo-server start" command
Now check your application, You can't find a CORS error now.

Comment: Be nice if you sourced the solution you provided.
https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/162